# Restored collection has different record count than dumped collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to make a copy of my collection. The collection is 'cold', no insertions or updates applied to it during the process. First thing I tried was

`db.source.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "copy" } ])`

Then I checked the number of documents in both source and copy to make sure everyrhing is OK (used `db.source.find({}).count()` and `db.copy.find({}).count()`):

```
source: 576551
copy: 576578
```

Surprise, sorpresa, Überraschung!!

I restarted mongod and tried it again with the same results. Next what I've tried was

```
mongodump -d base -c source
mongorestore -d base -c copy dump/base/source.bson
```

Same results.

Please help to understand what's going on and why the document count differs.

I use mongo 3.4, WiredTiger engine.

stats for source:

```
"ns" : "base.source",
"size" : 1175007734.0,
"count" : 576551,
"avgObjSize" : 2037,
"storageSize" : 354996224
```

stats for copy:

```
"ns" : "base.copy",
"size" : 1175058343.0,
"count" : 576578,
"avgObjSize" : 2037,
"storageSize" : 355389440
```

Possible reason: I have removed some documents from source collection just before making a copy. Maybe removed docs haven't been deleted completely and I need to flush changes or something like that?

Comment: This is [`collection.stats()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.stats/) right? What about [`collection.count()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.count/)?
 I'm guessing the latter is going to agree on the counts.

Comment: Then of course, once that misunderstunding is cleared up then read the documentation on `collection.stats()` [Unexpected shutdown](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.stats/#unexpected-shutdown-and-count). But in general I would take anything on `collection.stats()` as a "guide" rather than a "source of truth".

Comment: the source of truth was `db.source.find({}).count()` and `db.copy.find({}).count()`, and it just matches with stats. Edited th post.

Comment: I'm still inclined to think an unclean shutdown has been involved here, or some other critical error. You could loop each collection and increment a counter, which then will likely agree with the copy on both. In other words it seems more likely that the stats are busted on the "source" than the other option that the "copy" somehow came into possession of "phantom data". Noting this is 3.4, I'm pretty sure some "optimizations" are basically reading those "stats" as opposed to doing the "grunt work" of iterating like I suggest.